# Center tag works on link but not CSS or align attribute

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center a button that is an `<a>` tag. However, the only thing that will work is the `<center>` tag. I've tried using `<a style="text-align: center">Button</a>` and `<a align="center">Button</a>`, but none of the two worked. Why is it that only the center tag works?

My CSS is this:

```
.btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 200ms all;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #FFC964;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="btn">Button</a>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML!

Comment: Even though the question was answered, I added the HTML for anybody else who may find this helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<center>` tag is deprecated and is most likely to be removed in all the browsers. And `<a>` tag is inline in nature, so `text-align: center` should be given for it's parent block element:

```css
.make-center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="make-center">
  <a href="#">I am a link</a>
</div>
```

In the above code, the `<div class="make-center">` tag acts as a `<center>` tag.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I guess I forgot that the parent element has to use it, not the inline element.

Comment: Sure, mistakes happen buddy!

Comment: Also, I wasn't going to result to using ```<center>``` tag no matter what. That thing is evil. I doubt that it will be removed in all browsers, since may older sites rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `a` element have the `.btn` class?

Try adding this CSS to it:

```
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
```

Otherwise, create a jsfiddle for us which reproduces the problem.  You are not showing your entire CSS and markup.

Comment: Yes, my ```a``` element does have it.